# Intuition behind equivalent measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I can't understand the intuition behind equivalent measures.
Can someone explain it by using a "real - life example", specifically using probability measure and geometrical measures?

**Edit**: What I mean to ask is that if someone says "$P$ and $Q$ are equivalent measures", I don't know how or even why this can be used in the first place.

Basically how would you make an undergrad understand equivalent measures without using "no no words" like Borel and Lebesgue?

**Edit**:
Can someone provide reference to the "inventor" of this concept and the first research paper where this was ,entioned.

Comment: what are equivalent measures

Comment: why you think that there must be an intuition about a mathematical definition? In almost all cases there is no intuition at all for a mathematical concept. About the example: any measure of the form $f(x)\,d x$ for $f\neq 0$ almost everywhere is equivalent to the Lebesgue measure

Comment: @masacroso what about changing probability measure in pricing derivatives. There must be some intution to apply an abstract concept to real life scenario.

Comment: This question is extremely unclear and likely to be closed as it is.  What exactly is the intuition you are looking for?  Why we define equivalent measures the way we do?  How they are used?  Some specific applications of them? etc.

Comment: I can not stop laughing at your comment @Masacroso

Comment: [Check the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(measure_theory)#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20and%20specifically%20in,which%20events%20have%20measure%20zero.)

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom how is the article "intuitive" ?

Comment: When $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent measures they agree on what events are impossible (have probability zero). To me that is real-life enough and intuitive enough. In no-arbitrage theory in mathematical finance that concept shines brightly. Have you heard of the risk-neutral measure?

Comment: @Masacroso Mathematicians define things so that they can prove theorems about them. To be useful  a those definitions _must_ encapsulate  intuitive concepts. A  text or paper that proposes definitions without discussing what they _mean_ is badly written.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question is still very broad but I give it a try!

**Let us recall some basic definitions:**

Suppose that one has two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on some measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$ then consider the set of zero-measure events (impossible events) that are defined as

$$
\mathcal{N}_{\mu} = \{A \in \mathcal{A} : \mu(A) = 0\} 
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{N}_{\nu} = \{A \in \mathcal{A} : \nu(A) = 0\}
$$

Now $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equivalent iff $\mathcal{N}_{\mu} = \mathcal{N}_{\nu}$, this means that an event that is impossible under $\mu$ is impossible under $\nu$.

**Real-Life Example**:

Suppose you are a fisherman and you interested on catching some rare fish that is quite small and you have to choose between different fishing nets of different mash sizes.

The chance of catching this rare fish corresponds to a evaluating $\mu(A)$ where $\mu$ is a probability measure that gives you the chance of catching the fish while being on the sea for one day. Obviously you can not try out all fishing nets at once, however if you know that some **finishing nets are equivalent** and you observe that the **mesh size** of the net is too big to contain the rare fish (remember it is quite small) then you already know that **you don't have to try out any other fishing net that is equivalent to the used one**.

**Mathematical Importance**:

Similiar to the above example we usually dont care about the equivalence of measures, since this could be easily observed by checking the different mesh of the fishing nets directly without going to the sea.

The much more exciting question is the following: Suppose we know that one fishing net with a **special net mesh size** works to catch different kinds of fish that we are interested in. The chance of catching for example fish of type A is then given by $\lambda(A)$. Now having a different net of **bigger mesh sized**, where again the chance of catching fish of type A is given by $\nu(A)$, we immediatly observe that
$$
\mathcal{N}_{\lambda} \subset \mathcal{N}_{\nu},
$$
i.e. $\nu \ll \lambda$, since if a fish can escape the net due to the mesh size of $\lambda$ and since $\nu$ has **even bigger** mesh size we know that it always can also escape the finish net $\nu$ but not necessary vice versa. Now mathematical analysis/measure theory gives us the tools to calculate the chances of catching fish of type $B$, i.e. $\nu(B)$ while only using information from fishing from net $\lambda$ by applying theorems like Radon-Nikodym or similiar theorems.